# How do you properly use React.memo w/ event handler props from HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-memo

I've created a *very* simple example here..

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-with-function-props-09fgyo

As you can see, `ComponentB` renders just as many times as `ComponentB`.. even though it's wrapped in `memo` and isn't receiving `counter` as a prop.

If you open up the app in it's own page (https://09fgyo.csb.app/) and then use React DevTools to profile the page, you'll see that it's reporting it's cause for rendering is because the `onClick` prop changes (see screenshot)

[image]

So.. I know the reason that's happening is because whenever the HOC's state is changed, it re-renders itself, and in doing so, creates a new `handleButtonClick` because it's an arrow function.  So React looks at that and says, "oop.. it's a new function, rerender `ComponentB`!"

My question is.. what's the best pattern for fixing this kind of performance issue?

I mean.. I guess I could pass `setCounter` down into `CompnentB`, but that just seems icky.. tightly couples the HOC and it's state to `ComponentB`. (Update: Now that I think about it, can't do that either because I'd have to pass down `counter` as well in order to calculate the increment, and since that's changing, it would *also* cause a rerender.. ugh.)

I'm seriously at a loss.. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check the `useCallback` hook

Comment: @PYTHONDEVELOPER999 Care to elaborate a bit please?  How so?

Comment: `useCallback` memoizes a function. So on rerender if `useCallback` array dependency hasn't changed it doesn't recreate the function. Check reactjs docs.

Comment: @PYTHONDEVELOPER999 This is setting `handleButtonclick` to a `useCallback`, and the same behavior is persistent: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-with-function-props-w-usecallback-k7hsk1

Not sure how useCallback would be used to solve this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-with-function-props-w-usecallback-forked-ww3sr9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in the example given, `counter` _is_ a dependency, so of course the momoization of the handler doesn't work since `counter` is needed to calculate the increment value to pass to `setCounter`...  So still not seeing what you're getting at.  And the "RTFM" response isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: ok.. that's fair.. using useCallback w/ an empty dependency array works.  But won't most linters complain if you do that since `counter` is most definitely referenced inside of the handler?

Comment: please insepct my example carefully. I don't use any outside variables so there's no dependency.

Comment: Isn't `counter` _outside_ of the `handleButtonClick` callback function?

Comment: No. I renamed parameter name to `prev` to avoid confusion. Check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Ooooohhh.. you're passing a _function_ to `setCounter`, not just the increment value... I see!

Ok.. now _that_ is much clearer! Thank you!

Care to leave an answer on this so I can give you the credit @PYTHONDEVELOPER999 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useCallback` hook to wrap the function you pass to a child.

It will memoize the function and use the cache instead of recreating the function if none of the `useCallback` array dependency change.

Comment: Here's an example solution for anyone looking for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-memo-with-function-props-w-usecallback-solution-k7hsk1?file=/src/App.js